# Confounding variables are nested with treatment, not able to be measured, how to address the influence from confounding factors?

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, instrumental-variables, observational-study, regression-discontinuity

We gathered driving data from two cohorts of drivers belonging to the same age group. The first cohort, Group A, utilized System A (treatment group), whereas Group B drove vehicles without this system equipped. These two groups were based in different locations. The primary objective of our study is to evaluate the impact, if any, of System A on drivers' safety or overall driving outcomes.

However, the vehicles operated by Group A was a more luxurious and newer model. This is a confounding variables (the vehicle model and its year of production), which could impact driving outcomes. There was no pre-intervention data for Group A, these confounding variables are nested within the treatment. Group B (control group) drove the vehicle without System A equipped.

Would propensity scores or instrumental variable be a potential solution for dealing with these nested confounding variables. However, there is no variance on confounding variables in the treatment group. Could you recommend an approach to this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Couple of questions:  1) Was treatment randomly allocated, 2) How were locations selected, 3) are there any "luxurious and new models" in control?

Comment: I'm primarily concerned about the use of geography here to assign users to treatment and control.  Even if the subjects drove the same car, the geography could be a confounding factor.  You would have to make the -- incredibly strong, and likely erroneous -- assumption that the two locations are exchangeable.  While we do have the location covariate recorded, it is completely correlated with treatment meaning we are unable to disentangle the effect of location on the outcome.